# Is there a filter() opposite builtin?

Tags: python, functional-programming

Is there a function in Python that does the opposite of `filter`? I.e. keeps the items in the iterable that the callback returns `False` for? Couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No, there is no built-in inverse function for `filter()`, because you could simply *invert the test*. Just add `not`:

```
positive = filter(lambda v: some_test(v), values)
negative = filter(lambda v: not some_test(v), values)
```

The `itertools` module does have [`itertools.ifilterfalse()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilterfalse), which is rather redundant because inverting a boolean test is so simple. The `itertools` version always operates as a generator.

Comment: Your reasoning is not very convincing. The first case can already be written `positive = filter(some_test, values)` therefore what is asked for should be at least as simple as `negative = filter(not(some_test), values)`

Comment: CAREFUL! `not` is a builtin in python that evaluates immediately to either `True` or `False`. Function objects evaluate to `False`, and filter expects a function there, so this will give you a TypeError because the first argument is a Boolean. Other readers beware.

Comment: @Multihunter: and `not` is *not a built-in*. It's an operator.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're right, it's an operator. 
But, you can run the code. I ran it on Python 3, and definitely got a TypeError. And it's like I said; `not` operates on the function to return a boolean immediately. This isn't scala.
It should be something like `negative = filter(lambda e: not some_test(e), values)`

Comment: @Multihunter: or are you asking about Ross' comment? They were hoping for there to *be* a `not()` function or some other possible notation to invert the outcome of a function object, so they don't have to use a lambda. They are not claiming that the expression works today, they are complaining that it *doesn't* work.

Comment: @Multihunter: I added an answer that is solving the problem with the syntax in Ross' comment.

Answer (score 24):

You can do this with [`itertools.filterfalse`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse) or as [Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33989179/1473772) suggests, put a `not` somewhere inside the lambda you use in your filter.

Comment: +1 because itertools.filterfalse() addresses the OP's built-in requirement. I would add another +1 because it takes an iterable, and thus, adds only constant memory overhead. Using the `not` keyword, although would work, leads to verbose and more slightly awkward looking code.

Answer (score 8):

Another option:

```
from operator import not_
compose = lambda f, g: lambda x: f( g(x) )

...

ys = filter(compose(not_, predicate), values)
```

You may have a pre-rolled version of `compose()` available (e.g. in functional or [toolz](http://toolz.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html)).

Answer (score 6):

From [Ross Bencina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2013747)'s comment to [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33989179/655404):

> Your reasoning is not very convincing. The first case can already be
>   written
>
> ```
> positive = filter(some_test, values)
> ```
>
> therefore what is asked for should be at least as simple as
>
> ```
> negative = filter(not(some_test), values)
> ```

I would suggest using a simple negating wrapper function:

```
def _not(func):
    def not_func(*args, **kwargs):
        return not func(*args, **kwargs)
    return not_func
```

which allows to write the second line as above (with the added underscore or other distinction, since the `not` operator cannot and probably should not be overwritten):

```
negative = filter(_not(some_test), values)
```

Comment: This should be a built-in

Comment: @Koikos Agreed! Maybe under the name `negated`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, but I didn't wanted to have duplicated functions for my filter.
This is my solution to filter the items of a dictionary and be able to invert the selection.

```
req_table = {
    "ID_4001" : {"R_STAT":True, "V_STAT":False, "TYPE":"X", "VEL": 1},
    "ID_0051" : {"R_STAT":True, "V_STAT":True,  "TYPE":"X", "VEL": 23},
    "ID_0741" : {"R_STAT":True, "V_STAT":False, "TYPE":"Y", "VEL": 32},
    "ID_0701" : {"R_STAT":True, "V_STAT":False, "TYPE":"X", "VEL": 2353},
}

def count_prop(prop, with_val, rq_table, invert=False):
    return len(list(filter(lambda tc : (tc[1][prop] == with_val)^invert, rq_table.items())))

print("Items of type X: {}".format(count_prop("TYPE", "X", req_table)))
print("Items of type Y: {}".format(count_prop("TYPE", "X", req_table, invert=True)))
```

The trick is the `^` which acts as a enabled `not`.